# Is it possible to import a symlinked file and have the imported files imports resolve from the symlinked location and not the original one

Tags: node.js

eg:

A project directory looks like.

```
main.js
node_modules/dependency.js
linkedFile.js <-- this is a symlink to /someotherplace/linkedFile.js
package.json
```

main.js contains `import foo from 'linkedFile';`

linkedFile.js contains:

```
import dep from 'dependency';
```

However this throws an error because node looks for `node_modules/dependency.js` in `/someotherplace/` rather than in the project root.

The desired reason for this is so that some configuration files that are shared amongst many modules can be updated without having to put them in a module and having to run an update for each module before they are applied.

Is it possible to import the symlinked file in a way that causes the symlinked file imports to resolve from the symlink location. Or how could I resolve this problem in another way?

(Currently running node 8.15.0)

Comment: You should have the module get the configuration from or from a file named by an argument or an environmental variable and not use this solution.

Comment: so if the node module I am importing is date_fns then I should pass date_fns into the symlinked config file from wherever I import it?

Comment: Pass the config file to the module.